# With haskell shake build tool. Use a local static c library

Tags: haskell, shake

In one shake c project I created a static library called libbuild3a.a

I want to use it in a separate shake c project by directly supplying it in the source files. I get the following error when it tries to compile main.c which will be the exe.

Command line: gcc -c src3b/main.c -Lsrc3b/lib -lbuild3a -o build3b/src3b/main.o -MMD -MF build3b/src3b/main.m
Exit code: 1
Stderr:
src3b/main.c:2:10: fatal error: add.h: No such file or directory
 #include

Here is the shake project. It is a test project working towards calling c with haskell ffi.

```
build3b :: IO ()
build3b = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="build3b"} $ do
  let
    buildDir = "build3b"
    srcDir = "src3b"
  want [buildDir </> "run3b" <.> exe]

  buildDir </> "run3b" <.> exe %> \out -> do
        putInfo "============== entering exe creation ====================="

        --Do I need to load the static library?
        cs_main <- getDirectoryFiles "" [srcDir </>  "main.c", srcDir </> "lib" </> "libbuild3a.a"]
        need cs_main

        putInfo "showing main source file"
        mapM putInfo cs_main

        putInfo "starting compile of main.c main file"
        let
          os_main = [buildDir </> c -<.> "o" | c <- cs_main]
        need os_main
        mapM putInfo os_main

        --cmd_ "gcc -o" [out] os_main
        --cmd_ "gcc -o -Llib -lbuild3a" [out] os_main
        cmd_ "gcc -o -Lsrc3b/lib -lbuild3a" [out] os_main

  buildDir </> srcDir </>  "main.o" %> \out -> do
        putInfo $ "buildDir/main.o: " ++ show out
        let c = dropDirectory1 $ out -<.> "c"
        let m = out -<.> "m"
        cmd_ "gcc -c" [c] "-o" [out] "-MMD -MF" [m]
        --cmd_ "gcc -c" [c] "-Lsrc3b/lib -lbuild3a -o" [out] "-MMD -MF" [m]
        neededMakefileDependencies m

  {-I added this as shake complained about not having a rule for libbuild3a.o
    I tried to deconstruct the library useing `ar`. Got rid of the no rule failure,
    but did not help in finding add.h in main.c-}     
  buildDir </> "src3b" </> "lib" </> "libbuild3a.o" %> \out -> do
        putInfo $ "buildDir/lib/libbuild3a.o: " ++ show out
        let c = dropDirectory1 $ out

        libs <- getDirectoryFiles "" [srcDir </> "lib" </> "libbuild3a.a"]
        need libs
        --cmd_ "ar rcs" [out] os_tq84
        --[cmd_ "ar -xv l add.o answer.o" [out] l | l <- libs]
        cmd_ "ar -xv libbuild3a.a add.o answer.o" [out] libs
```

And here is the main.c trying to use it. This will will be the exe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <add.h>
#include <answer.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  setSummand(5);

  printf("5 + 7 = %d\n", add(7));

  printf("And the answer is: %d\n", answer());

  return 0;
}
```

Would it be better just to use the source files and not bother with the .a library. Or perhaps us `ar` to decompose the library into it's .o files? I tried that in the last rule with no effect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like it should migrate to code review

Comment: "better" for who? What's the final purpose of the code?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard It may be on-topic for CR but please don't use that as a reason to VTC. Instead flag it for moderator intervention and explain how it is on-topic there. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by off-topic, CR and VTC. Is it just that it needs to be tagged differently? I am using the haskell shake build module. The point of the code is to learn to build a haskell project with shake, that also generates and uses a static c library.

Comment: VTC retracted..

Comment: I checkout out CR. I guess that is where it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by linking the static library with ghc options.

The problem now is that the main_exe does not see the changes in the libsupply.a file. I need to figure out how to put a need on it, even though the call which creates the library

```
cmd_ "ar rcs" [out] co
```

is the last expression in the rule.

Here is the new source:

```
build4 :: IO ()
build4 = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="build4"} $ do
  let buildDir = "build4"
      srcDir = "src4"
  want [srcDir </>  "libsupply.a"]
  want [buildDir </> "main_exe" <.> exe]

  buildDir </> "main_exe" <.> exe %> \out -> do

      cmd_
          "ghc"
          ("src4" </> "main.hs")
          "-isrc"
          "-Lsrc4"
          "-lsupply"
          "-outputdir"
          "build4"
          "-o"
          out


  srcDir </> "libsupply.a" %> \out -> do
    putInfo $ "in build4/libsupply.a: " ++ ( show out)
    cs <- getDirectoryFiles "" [srcDir </> "*.c"]
    need  cs

    let co = [buildDir </> c -<.> "o" | c <- cs]
    need co

    cmd_ "ar rcs" [out] co


  --build the .c files required for the library
  buildDir </> "//*.o" %> \out -> do
    putInfo $ "in build_dir </> //*.o: " ++ ( show out)
    let c = dropDirectory1 $ out -<.> "c"
    let m = out -<.> "m"
    cmd_ "gcc -c" [c] "-o" [out] "-MMD -MF" [m]
    neededMakefileDependencies m
```